# Apache Drill - creating own table by CTAS

Tags: apache, apache-drill

The CTAS commans is: `CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS <query>;`
However, before creating table I have to create schema.  I can't do it, moreover I can't use existing schema because for each installed yet schema I get error:
`schema cp is immutable`. Hence solution is create new schema.  The problem is that I can't find any example of this command.

Comment: The Drill [docs](http://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas-command/) are pretty straight forward and it has examples. Did you check it?

Comment: Yes, but firstly I have to create schema. In your link there is no it.

Comment: what do you mean by schema here? They clearly mentioned - **You can only create new tables in workspaces. You cannot create tables in other storage plugins such as Hive and HBase.** Here table means you can create json, csv or parquet file

Comment: On which database are you querying and where do you want to create table?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS (SELECT * FROM hive.mytable)`. It returns error that cp is immutable (and the same for each another existing schema).  Could you help me tell:  Is it possible to cache entire hive table into memorty in order to improve performance. Now, it is too slow.

Comment: where do you want to create this table `new_table_name`?

Comment: I try in each schema - no effect. Where ? Anywhere.   What about caching into memory (it is my aim in real)

Comment: I am not aware of caching hive table in memory using drill. I don't think it's possible. Still you can ask a different question. May others do some help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using CTAS, as per the [docs](http://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas-command/) you can only create new tables in workspaces. You cannot create tables in other storage plugins such as Hive and HBase.

You can store table data in one of three formats:

- csv
- parquet
- json

Steps to create table using CTAS:

1. Set `store.format`:

   ```
   alter session set `store.format`='json';
   ```
2. set location at which table (*better to call file*) is created:

   Go to dfs plugin: http://localhost:8047/storage/dfs

   In "workspaces", add writable (mutable) workspace. Eg:

   ```
    "tmp": {
        "location": "/tmp",
         "writable": true,
          }
   ```

   do notice  `"writable": true`
3. Use workspace:

   ```
   use dfs.tmp;
   ```
4. Fire CTAS command. Eg:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS (SELECT * FROM hive.mytable);
   ```

Check `/tmp/abc` directory, you will find JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dfs or any other storage plugin which uses local file system.
eg : create table dfs.test.`temp_count` (user_count) as select t1.data as userParams from s3device.`<File-Path>` t1 limit 1